# What is Haskell's Data.Typeable?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

I've come across references to Haskell's `Data.Typeable`, but it's not clear to me why I would want to use it in my code.

What problem does it solve, and how?

Answer (score 48):

`Data.Typeable` is an encoding of an well known approach (see e.g. Harper) to implementing delayed (dynamic) type checking in a statically typed language -- using a **universal** type.

Such a type wraps code for which type checking would not succeed until a later phase. Rather than reject the program as ill-typed, the compiler passes it on for runtime checking.

The style originated in Abadi et al., and developed for Haskell by Cheney and Hinze as a wrapper to represent all dynamic types, with the `Typeable` class appearing as part of the SYB work of SPJ and Lammel.

---

*Reference*

- Martín Abadi, Luca Cardelli, Benjamin Pierce and Gordon Plotkin, "[Dynamic Typing in a Statically Typed Language](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-47.pdf)", ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems (TOPLAS), 1991.
- James Cheney and Ralf Hinze, "[A lightweight implementation of generics and dynamics](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/HW02.pdf)", Haskell '02: Proceedings of the 2002 ACM SIGPLAN Workshop on Haskell, 2002.
- Lammel, Ralf and Jones, Simon Peyton, "[Scrap your boilerplate: a practical design pattern for generic](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/hmap.ps) programming, TLDI '03: Proceedings of the 2003 ACM SIGPLAN International Workshop on Types in Languages Design and Implementation, 2003
- Harper, 2011, Practical Foundations for Programming Languages.

---

Even in the text books: dynamic types (with typeable representations) are statically typed languages with only one type, Harper ch 20:

> #### 20.4 Untyped Means Uni-Typed
>
> The untyped λ-calculus may be faithfully embedded in a
>   typed language with recursive types. This means that every
>   untyped λ-term has a representation as a typed expression
>   in such a way that execution of the representation of a
>   λ-term corresponds to execution of the term itself. This
>   embedding is *not* a matter of writing an interpreter for
>   the λ-calculus in ℒ{+×⇀µ} (which we could surely do), but
>   rather a direct representation of untyped λ-terms as typed
>   expressions in a language with recursive types.
>
> The key observation is that the *untyped* λ-calculus is
>   really the *uni-typed* λ-calculus! It is not the *absence*
>   of types that gives it its power, but rather that it has
>   *only one* type, namely the recursive type
>
> D = µt.t → t.

Comment: "the untyped lambda calculus is really the uni-typed lambda calculus" - a beautiful pun!

Comment: Could you explain the difference between an "interpreter" and a "direct representation" in Harper's sense?

Comment: "The style originated in Abadi et al" -- their paper clearly acknowledges that there were existing implementations of the system they describe before they wrote the paper, dating back to Simula 67, and that their contribution was to provide a formal semantic definition for it.

Answer (score 17):

It's a library that allows, among other things, naming types. If a type `a` is declared `Typeable`, then you can get its name using `show $ typeOf x` where `x` is any value of type `a`. It also features [limited type-casting](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast).

(This is somewhat similar to C++'s RTTI or dynamic languages' reflection.)

Comment: No.  `Typeable` does not allow casting, that's in `Dynamic`.  And `Dynamic` does not allow casting between different types, because it forms a safe wrapper around `unsafeCoerce`.  `Typeable` fits in as part of `Dynamic`'s safe wrapper.  It provides the ability to get a runtime representation of a type.  Nothing more.

Comment: @Carl: `cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b` -- all you need is `Typeable`, no `Dynamic` involved! Using `Typeable` and `cast` you can in fact roll your own `Dynamic` fairly easily...

Comment: @sclv, almost, but `dynApply` and `dynApp` can't yet be done using the `Typeable` machinery without `unsafeCoerce`. That's slated to happen soon, however; Richard Eisenberg, Stephanie Weirich, and a couple other luminaries have been working on it.

Answer (score 8):

One of the earliest descriptions I could find of a `Data.Typeable`-like library for Haskell is by John Peterson from 1992: http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr1022.pdf

The earliest "official" paper I know of introducing the actual `Data.Typeable` library is the first Scrap Your Boilerplate paper from 2003: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/hmap/index.htm

I'm sure there's lots of intervening history that someone here can chime in with!

Answer (score 4):

The [Data.Typeable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Typeable.html) class is used primarily for generic programming in the [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Generic_programming/SyB) (SYB) style.  See also [Data.Data](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Data.html)

The idea is that SYB defines a collection combinators for performing operations such as printing, counting, searching, substiting, etc in a uniform manner over a variety of user-created types.  The `Typeable` typeclass provides the necessary plumbing.

In modern GHC, you can just say `deriving Data.Typeable` when defining your own type in order to provide it with the necessary instances.