# Haskell: Filtering by type

Tags: haskell

For any particular type `A`:

```
data A = A Int
```

is is possible to write this function?

```
filterByType :: a -> Maybe a
```

It should return `Just . id` if value of type `A` is given, and `Nothing` for value of any other types.

Using any means (GHC exts, TH, introspection, etc.)

*NB. Since my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025660/haskell-converting-between-typeclasses/) about Haskell typesystem was criticized by the community as "terribly oversimplified", I feel the need to state, that this is a purely academic interest in Haskell typesystem limitations, without any particular task behind it that needs to be solved.*

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb

Comment: FYI, what you are calling "limitations", Haskell programmers tend to regard as "essential features". We use properties like parametricity to *reason* about our code, and in many cases to *intentionally* restrict what can be done with it, to preserve internal invariants or to use "unsafe" primitives to implement safe APIs. Read, for example, the paper *Lazy Functional State Threads* (available online). For another use of that technique, see `Data.Reflection` in the `reflection` package.

Comment: For a very different way to use parametricity, see `Data.Constraint.Forall` in the `constraints` package (read the latest version on GitHub, as it's changed a lot recently). As for reasoning, parametricity automatically ensures certain aspects of correctness of `Functor` and `Traversable` instances, makes sure functions on type-aligned sequences (AKA thrists) preserve order properly, etc.

Comment: Presumably you actually want a type like `a -> Maybe A`. Then it is vaguely possible if you allow yourself to add a typeclass constraint on `a`. But I suspect that this line of questions comes from interpreting the keyword `class` as if it were relating to the OOP notion of class -- which it very much isn't.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, if we allow adding constraint, than we don't need anything else, `Typeable a` would be the most sensible solution. I understand the difference between OOP classes, and typeclasses. What I didn't understand is what Antal and you said in your answers - how type and typeclass resolution works in GHC. To make it clearer to myself, I have asked those questions. I'm satisfied with the result as now I have better understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't write this function.  In Haskell, values without type class constraints are *parametric* in their type variables.  This means we know that they have to behave exactly the same when instantiated at any particular type¹; in particular, and relevant to your question, this means they cannot inspect their type parameters.

This design means that that all types can be *erased* at run time, which GHC does in fact do.  So even stepping outside of Haskell qua Haskell, unsafe tricks won't be able to help you, as the *runtime* representation is sort of parametric, too.

If you want something like this, [josejuan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033925/237428) of using [`Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html)'s [`cast`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) operation is a good one.

---

¹ Modulo some details with `seq`.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`cast`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) at [Data.Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html)

```
cast :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
```

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600380/what-is-haskells-data-typeable)

Example

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable

data A = A Int deriving (Show, Typeable)
data B = B String deriving (Show, Typeable)

showByType :: Typeable a =>a ->String
showByType x = case (cast x, cast x) of
                 (Just (A y), _) ->"Type A: " ++ show y
                 (_, Just (B z)) ->"Type B: " ++ show z
```

then

```
> putStrLn $ showByType $ A 4
Type A: 4
> putStrLn $ showByType $ B "Peter"
Type B: "Peter"
>
```

Without `Typeable` derivation, no information exists about the underlying type, you can anyway perform some `cast` transformation like

```
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

filterByType :: a -> Maybe a
filterByType x = if SOMECHECK then Just (unsafeCoerce x) else Nothing
```

but, where is that information?

Then, you cannot write your function (or I don't know how) but in some context (binary memory inspection, template haskell, ...) may be.

Comment: Is it possible to do without the constraint `Typeable` on the `a`? Can this function accept all types?

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich no (in a secure way)

Comment: Insecure way then?

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Typeable.html#eqT

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look at in the `eqT` source. Can you please update the answer with a working example of function with requested type signature and explain why it is unsafe, and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A function of type `a -> Maybe a` is trivial. It's just `Just`. A function `filterByType :: a -> Maybe b` is impossible.

This is because once you've compiled your program, `a` and `b` are gone. There is no run time type information in Haskell, at all.

However, as mentioned  in another answer you can write a function:

```
cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
```

The reason you can write this is because the constraint `Typeable a` tells the compiler to, where ever this function is called, pass along a run-time dictionary of values specified by `Typeable`. These are useful operations that can build up and tear down a great range of Haskell types. The compiler is incredibly smart about this and can pass in the right dictionary for virtually any type you use the function on.

Without this run-time dictionary, however, you cannot do anything. Without a constraint of `Typeable`, you simply do not get the run-time dictionary.

All that aside, if you don't mind my asking, what exactly do you want this function for? Filtering by a type is not actually useful in Haskell, so if you're trying to do that, you're probably trying to solve something the wrong way.

Comment: "A function of type a -> Maybe a is trivial." Please provide the example of this function that will return `Just . id` for `A` and `Nothing` for everything else, and I'll mark your answer as accepted. Without constraints on the input argument, please. "Filtering by a type is not actually useful in Haskell" - currently accepted answer states that it's impossible to do this in Haskell, doesn't matter if one find it useful or useless... I don't want it for anything, it's just this (justifiable) brick wall in Haskell typesystem that I find interesting.